# Django - How to use delete() in ManyToMany relationships to only delete a single relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model `Voucher` that can be allocated to several `users`.

I used a `M2M` relationship for it.

I want, in the template, the possibility to delete the voucher allocated to the logged in user, and the logged in user only (not all relationships).

The problem I have is that the current model deletes the entire model for all users, instead of the single user requesting "delete".

The alternative would obvioulsy be to simply create a model `Voucher` on a ForeignKey, but something tells I can probably do it with a M2M in the views.

Is there a way to focus my delete function specific to the user? In the example below, I tried to filter based on `user.request` which is not working. Looking at the data inside the model, users IDs are listed. Is it not what `request.user` does?

**models**

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

**views**

```
def delete_voucher(request, voucher_id):
    voucher = Voucher.objects.filter(pk=voucher_id).filter(user=request.user)
    voucher.delete()
    return redirect('account')
```

**template**

```
<a class="button3 btn-block mybtn tx-tfm" href="{% url 'delete-voucher' voucher.id %}">Delete</a>
```

**url**

```
path('delete_voucher/<voucher_id>', views.delete_voucher, name='delete-voucher'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.remove` method. [See the M2M documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

So

```
def delete_voucher(request, voucher_id):
    voucher = Voucher.objects.filter(pk=voucher_id).filter(user=request.user)
    voucher.user.remove( request.user) 
    # note, more readable if the M2M field has a plural name voucher.users
    return redirect('account')
```

It's symmetrical so you could also do `request.user.voucher_set.remove( voucher)`

It may help to know that there's an intermediate table maintaining the relationship between a `voucher` object (row in the vouchers table) and a `user` object. Each row in this table contains a foreign key to one `user` and a foreign key to one `voucher`. `.remove` deletes the row in this intermediate table, leaving the `user` and `voucher` objects unchanged.